# Two background color in a frameLayout Android

Tags: android

In android xml we set the background as following

```
android:background="#FF88FF"
```

Now In frameLayout how can I use tow background color. E.g. top 50% should be red bottom 50% should be black

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.79"
    android:background="#FF88FF"
    android:padding="25dp" >
</FrameLayout>
```

How to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the custom drawable, which will include 2 shapes - 2 rectangles. Something like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
               android:dither="true">
            <solid android:color="color1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
               android:dither="true">
            <solid android:color="color2"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Please note, that absolute values are used here for sizes. For relative sizes I think you should create custom `Drawable` programmatically by extending `Drawable` class.